# Interlocked.Increment not working with my Get variable name

Tags: wpf, multithreading, inotifypropertychanged

I have `WPF` application and my work `method` play my files in different threads

This is my `Global` variable that update my `UI`:

```
public static int _totalFilesSent;
```

Now because i am implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my model i have also this:

```
public static int TotalFilesSent
{
    get { return _totalFilesSent; }
    set
    {
        _totalFilesSent = value;
        OnStaticlPropertyChanged("TotalFilesSent");
    }
}
```

(i didn't add the event function because this is not relevant here).

So every time i am update my `Global variable` this way:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref _totalFilesSent );
```

Now because i need to update my `UI` with my `INotifyPropertyChanged` event i need to use `TotalFilesSent` instead of `_totalFilesSent` but in this way i got this compilation error:

> A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an
>   out or ref parameter.

What does it mean and how can i solved it ?

Comment: Why can't you use the code that works? You have working code there.

Comment: When i am using _totalFilesSent instead of TotalFilesSent this is not update my UI

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/979033/user979033) *also* your account? At least it has the same typo in `OnStaticlPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may easily raise the `StaticPropertyChanged` event after calling `Interlocked.Increment`:

```
private static int _totalFilesSent;

public static int TotalFilesSent
{
    get { return _totalFilesSent; }
}

public static void IncrementTotalFilesSent()
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref _totalFilesSent);
    OnStaticPropertyChanged("TotalFilesSent");
}
```

Comment: i still need the Set for other purposes

Comment: Then put it back in place?!

Comment: And what about IncrementTotalFilesSent() ? i still need it ?

Comment: Apparently you need it when you want to use Interlocked.Increment, as that can't be used with a property.